# Exception output is not right

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def readVal(valType, requestMsg, errorMsg):
    while True:
        val = input(requestMsg)
        try:
            val = valType(Val)
            return Val
        except:
            print(errorMsg)

print (readVal(int, 'Enter int:', 'Not as int.'))
```

And I got the following result when I input 4, 5, 2.

> Enter int:4 Not as int. Enter int:5 Not as int. Enter int:2 Not as
>   int.

I cann't get the right answer which is 4, 5, 2. What's wrong with my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the syntax highlighting indicates, `Val` isn't the same as `val`. That is a typo causing a `NameError`. The bigger problem is that your program is hiding the NameError from you because you told it to convert any exception, no matter what caused it, to a single message.

You probably intended to catch `ValueError`, which `int` will throw on unexpected input.